# How to create your own bucket for Google Cloud Vision?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

Is it possible to create your own bucket with images where you can add extra information for each image. Then use Google Cloud Vision to search like they do now but as an extra also search the image in your bucket?

Reason: I have some images that, when I search them with Google Cloud Vision, return almost no text. For this reason I would add these type of images to a bucket and manually add more information. The next time a user takes a photo of the same thing, it needs to search inside this bucket and if found return the extra information about this image.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. What problem are you running in to?

Comment: I cannot find exactly what API paths that I need to use to do this. I found something about AutoML now. But I see that the minimum is 10 images/label. And that is something I will not have in the beginning.

Comment: Oh, you want to programmatically create a bucket in your code instead of creating one with gsutil?

Comment: I think the best is to use google autoML bucket. I just need to find a way to make it learn with the limited photos that I will have to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the product search api on vision api:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/how-to

It allows you to build your own image catalog and each image can be annotated with image metadata.

And then you can use image similarity search of the API to achieve what you want.

See a video tutorial here as well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOdUYTO1jJY&t=539s

To manage image catalog they provides a bunch of APIs and also you can use a the batch processing API

Answer (score 0):

Sure. What you'll end up wanting to do is to set up a bucket so that every time an image is added to it, Cloud Vision is invoked on it, and the result is added to some sort of searchable index. There's a tutorial on how to build exactly this to power a Google Photos type thing: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/use-cloud-pubsub-cloud-storage-app-engine

Comment: Is this possible to add your own unique index to it? So next time a client uploads a sort like photo that it returns this index in the api call that I make? And not only the ocr, labels, etc. So I don't need to to compare the result anymore to possoble hits in my database...

Comment: It's easy to check for an identical file using its hash, but if you wanted to check for the same image using some sort of image fingerprint, that's thornier. Image hashing is complex, but there are some libraries you could investigate: https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/

Comment: Looks very interesting. Will take a look into it